# How to use document ready function after loaded all components in the page angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to perform some jQuery action after full page loading in Angular 6. I have 3 components in single page.header, body and footer. I have tried `ngAfterViewInit in footer component`. But I could not able to access the DOM element fully. Kindly suggest if you know.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: i am using ngx-permission for role based menus. After loading all menus i need to add some class through jquery action. This is my goal.

Comment: `After loading all menus i need to add some class through jquery action` ← How are menus loaded? You could probably hook your event logic from that. As far as adding classes why using jquery? Why not use one of the many options available from angular?

Answer (score 0):

*you can try this*

*html file*

```
<li>
   <a href="#" id="footer-item">about</a>
</li>
```

*component.ts file*

```
declare let $: any;

@Component({
selector: 'app-footer',
templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})

ngDoCheck() {
    $('#footer-item').addClass('active');
 }
```